# Ionic 2 : How to check current page is root page in Ionic 2?

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I just want to check current page name in Ionic 2 for that I have used NavController in app.component.ts, but this giving an error that **No provider for NavController**. Please suggest me some solution, Thanks in advance.

This is My Code below :

```
constructor(platform: Platform,public alertCtrl: AlertController,public navControll:NavController) {
    this.platform=platform;
    //this.nav=nav;
    platform.ready().then(()=>{
     if(navControll.canGoBack())
     {
         platform.registerBackButtonAction(()=>this.myHandlerFunction());
     }  
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
})
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In app.component you do not need to import NavController, because you have:

```
@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
```

instead you can try this:

```
this.nav
```

in other components:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
export class Page {
   constructor(
      public navController: NavController
   ) {}
}
this.navController
```

to see what you can do with NavController check [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/) link.
I think you must work with page index not page name.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `navControll.canGoBack()` method.

It'll return true if there's a page to go back, so if it returns false it's in the root.

Comment: Thanx Gabriel for the suggestion, one more query  i have that what should i suppose to import for navControll in app.component.ts. because when I import NavController in 'ionic-angular ' it showing me an error. Thanx in advance... :)